# Spring boot cannot retrieve html page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I can't retrieve the neither blog.html nor other htmls with trying localhost:8080/blog . When i am trying to access /blog path i get Whitelabel Error Page so its 404 not found and in the console log i am seeing " `ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Path represents URL or has "url:" prefix: [classpath:/templates/blog.html]`"  warning. When i change my @controller to @restcontroller i can access /blog path but with @controller i can't access it . Thank you in advance

my project structure :

[image]

Testt.java so my controller class :

```
@Controller public class Testt {

    @GetMapping(path = "/blog")     public String getAbout() {      return "blog";  }

}
```

SecurityConfig.java so my spring security config class :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).permitAll();
    }

}
```

EstoreAppApplication.java so my boostrapper springbootjava class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EstoreAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EstoreAppApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

my application properties :

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

Comment: why did you add spring.mvc.view properteis? can you try and remove them?

Comment: i removed then i faced with  "Circular view path [blog]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/blog] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! "      error. The strange thing is i copied all of my html files to src main web app folder then right now i can access all of them but as you can imagine i can't navigate through controller . So i can open index.html then can navigate to blog.html but when i try /blog it returns 404 again.

Comment: see my answer below. i am assuming you havent added a templating library to your project just yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, as you didn't mention your pom.xml file,but:

1. Make sure to have the following dependency inside it, I'm assuming you are missing a templating library and I am choosing Thymeleaf here.

.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. Remove the `spring.mvc.view.` properties.
3. Try again.